# How to get previous tab index of QTabBar on currentChanged

Tags: python, c++, qt, pyqt, qtabbar

I have a dialog with a `QTabBar` that is used to display and edit some information contained in other widgets of the dialog. The idea was when the tab is changed, the `currentChanged` signal could be emitted, then used to save the data that was previously displayed and pull up some new data afterwards.

The data is saved in a list whose elements correspond with tab index. Basically, in order to do this I need to know the new and old index when the `currentChanged` signal is emitted, but this signal only gives the new index.

How can this be done? If a minimal example is needed I can provide one, but I am basically using `QTabBar.currentChanged.connect` to connect this signal to a function that handles the saving and displaying of information on the dialog.

Comment: Just keep track of the currently active index. In `currentChanged` handler, you would have the new index (comes with the signal) and the old (the one you stored). Do your work, then update your stored active index to the new one.

Comment: Good call. This completely slipped my mind!